# magento 2, I need to add dompdf Library Without using composer in my extension

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pdf, composer

I have created an extension for HTML to PSD by using **[dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)** Library.

I had tried to using composer and it's working fine.

**But** I need this Library in my custom extension. When any user add extension 
directly, it will working fine.

Please let me know proper suggestion with some demo code.

Comment: Give me any solution on it.

Answer (score 0):

If users can install your extension via composer, add `dompdf` to your `require` section:

```
"require" : {
  "dompdf/dompdf": "0.8.0"
}
```

This way it is automatically installed together with your extension.

If you want to create a package that users can drop into `app/code`, you can add the `dompdf` sources next to your own code and copy its autoloading declarations to your own composer.json:

```
app/code
+-- Your_Extension
    +-- Dompdf
    |   +-- src
    |   +-- lib
    +-- composer.json
    +-- registration.php
    +...
```

Add to your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Dompdf\\" : "Dompdf/src/"
    },
    "classmap" : ["Dompdf/lib/"]
},
```

Comment: How to call Dompdf into my controller Or helper Or model. Because I have tried to not getting how to call DOMPDF class or object into my extension.

Comment: @HiteshVaghasiya follow the Dompdf documentation. For example: `use Dompdf\Dompdf;`, then `$dompdf = new Dompdf();`

Comment: Hello Sir , I have tried using all the way as you given but getting Error : Fatal error: Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found in Path.

Comment: if you developed in `app/code`, run `composer dump-autoload` to update the composer autoloader

Comment: Hello Sir, I have tried  But Still not getting a solution, I am getting same Error  "Fatal error" after composer dump-autoload. Can you please explain in depth Or Give me Demo.

Comment: Hello everyone, this issue of integrating old (or non psr compliant) libs is so spread in M2 since composer is in its core, I hope to find a good guide answering some of these questions : where is the proper place to put sdk? in lib/internal or in modules dir (latter seems to forbid reuse in other modules) ? how to include the autoloader in the module (in registration.php seem to cause issues) ?